# More than one row returns oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

tbl_phone

```
id  clnt_cd   phone_type   Phone_no
__  ________  __________  __________
1   12345       R          09030102
2   67891       B          043-2020
3   27282       M          09030301
4   12345       M          08202021
```

tbl_client

```
clnt_cd   first_name    last_name
_______   ___________   _________
12345      Eren         Jaeger
67891      Mikasa       Jaeger
```

and i have script in oracle like this:

```
SELECT tc.first_name, tc.last_name, (SELECT FROM tbl_phone WHERE phone_type = 'R' ) AS "Residence Telephone Number", (SELECT FROM tbl_phone WHERE phone_type = 'B') AS "Office Telephone Number", (SELECT FROM tbl_phone WWHERE phone_type = 'M') AS "Cellphone Number" FROM tbl_client tc INNER JOIN tbl_phone tp ON tc.clnt_cd = TP.clnt_cd
```

The problem is that error always shows ORA-01427: Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

The output i'm trying to get is

```
clint_cd  first_name  last_name  residence telephone number  Office telephone number  cellphone number
________  __________  _________  __________________________  _______________________  ________________
12345      Eren         Jaeger     09030102                    N/A                      08202021
67891      Mikasa       Jaeger     N/A                         043-2020                 N/A
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN once for each phone number type,

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select *
from tbl_client c join
     (select p.clnt_cd,
             max(case when phone_type = 'R' then Phone_no end) as r_phone,
             max(case when phone_type = 'B' then Phone_no end) as b_phone,
             max(case when phone_type = 'M' then Phone_no end) as m_phone
      from tbl_phone p
      group by p.clnt_cd
     ) p
     using (clnt_cd);
```

Comment: Hi! would like to ask what if there are many tables in the inner join?

Comment: @ElijahLeis . . . This answers the question that you asked here, and that question is specifically about two tables.  I see no issue with adding additional `join`s, but if that is an issue, ask a *new* question.

Comment: Already made another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263647/subquery-returns-too-many-rows

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT c.*,
       p.residence_phone_no,
       p.business_phone_no,
       p.cellphone_phone_no
FROM   tbl_client c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT p.clnt_cd,
                  p.phone_type,
                  p.phone_no
           FROM   tbl_phone p
         )
         PIVOT (
           MAX( phone_no ) FOR phone_type IN (
             'R' AS residence_phone_no,
             'B' AS business_phone_no,
             'M' AS cellphone_phone_no
           )
         )
       ) p
       ON ( c.clnt_cd = p.clnt_cd )
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_phone ( id, clnt_cd, phone_type, Phone_no ) AS
SELECT 1,   12345,       'R',          '09030102' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   67891,       'B',          '043-2020' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   27282,       'M',          '09030301' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   12345,       'M',          '08202021' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tbl_client ( clnt_cd, first_name, last_name ) AS
SELECT 12345,      'Eren',         'Jaeger' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 67891,      'Mikasa',       'Jaeger' FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> CLNT_CD | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | RESIDENCE_PHONE_NO | BUSINESS_PHONE_NO | CELLPHONE_PHONE_NO
> ------: | :--------- | :-------- | :----------------- | :---------------- | :-----------------
>   67891 | Mikasa     | Jaeger    | null               | 043-2020          | null              
>   12345 | Eren       | Jaeger    | 09030102           | null              | 08202021
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db74c3120e7e082906f9c63f74d2fc96)*

Answer (score 0):

This will give each type of phone number for your clients, or null if they don't have that type. Note that I am assuming a client will only have one instance of any given type of phone.

```
SELECT tc.first_name
     , tc.last_name
     , phr.phone_no AS "Residence Telephone Number"
     , phb.phone_no AS "Office Telephone Number"
     , phm.phone_no AS "Cellphone Number"      
FROM tbl_client tc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_phone phr ON tc.clnt_cd = phr.clnt_cd
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_phone phb ON tc.clnt_cd = phb.clnt_cd
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_phone phm ON tc.clnt_cd = phm.clnt_cd
WHERE phr.phone_type = 'R'
AND   phb.phone_type = 'B'
AND   phm.phone_type = 'M'
/
```

---

For very large volumes of data I would be tempted to use subquery factoring (the WITH clause) to select from TBL_PHONE just the once.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your query is that you missed the `clnt_cd` predicate in your scalar subqueries (also the column name but I assume that was a typo or copy & paste issue).

```
select phone_no from tbl_phone where phone_type = 'M'
```

returns 09030301 and 08202021, hence the 'more than one row' error.

Fixed version:

```
select tc.first_name
     , tc.last_name
     , (select phone_no from tbl_phone tp where tp.clnt_cd = tc.clnt_cd and phone_type = 'R') as "Residence Telephone Number"
     , (select phone_no from tbl_phone tp where tp.clnt_cd = tc.clnt_cd and phone_type = 'B') as "Office Telephone Number"
     , (select phone_no from tbl_phone tp where tp.clnt_cd = tc.clnt_cd and phone_type = 'M') as "Cellphone Number"
from   tbl_client tc;
```